# MikTex for 32 bit windows 7

Tags: miktex2.9

please anybody provide me the link to download MikTex for 32 bit windows 7.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! https://miktex.org/download??? You need to open the "All downloads" section.

Comment: https://miktex.org/ (there search for 32 bit miktex). welcome to tex.se!

Comment: I made a video tutorial a while ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4uIAOPq1UE

Comment: http://miktex.org/download , once there tap on "All downloads"  select Basic Installer 32 bit

Answer (score 5):

Go to [All downloads](https://miktex.org/download#all) on MiKTeX.org, and you should have this page:

[image]

Comment: Doesn’t work anymore...